# why is auth().onAuthStateChangedtriggered multiple times?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, authentication

The problem is that by launching the page in question, the method is called several times. As soon as I click the `RightContent` the same method is called even more times. I tried solving with a boolean variable used as a flag, but it seems that the program avoids this thing.
The code:

```
auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => { 
const preferredArtistRef = firestore().collection('preferredArtist')
if (user) {
  isSignedUser(true)
  setUid(user.uid)
  preferredArtistRef  //<--- to check if the page is already in favorites
    .get()
    .then(querySnapshot => {
      querySnapshot.forEach(documentSnapshot => {
        setDocumentId(documentSnapshot.id)
        if (documentSnapshot.data().uid == uid && documentSnapshot.data().artist == nameArtist) {
          setPreferred(true)
          console.log('add')  //<--- this appears many times in the console
        }
      })
    })
} else {
  isSignedUser(false)
}
  });
```

Instead the code of the `RightContent` of a card is:

```
const RightContent = () =>
<FontAwesome
  name={star}
  color='#673AB7'
  size={visibleIcon}
  onPress={() => {
    const preferredArtistRef = firestore().collection('preferredArtist')
    if (preferred) {
      setPreferred(false)  //delete to favorites
      preferredArtistRef
        .doc(documentId)
        .delete()
        .then(() => {
          console.log('Artist remove')
        })
        .catch((error) => alert(error))
    } else {
      setPreferred(true)  //add to favorites
      preferredArtistRef
        .add({
          uid: uid,
          artist: nameArtist
        })
        .then(querySnapshot => {
          console.log('Artist added in prefer')
        })
        .catch((error) => alert(error))
    }
  }}
  style={styles.star}
/>
```

EDIT: I add all code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, ActivityIndicator, View, Image, Dimensions, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import { StackActions } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { Card } from 'react-native-paper';
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';
import firestore from '@react-native-firebase/firestore';
import FontAwesome from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
import FontAwesome5 from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome5';
import AntDesign from 'react-native-vector-icons/AntDesign';

const ArtistScreen = ({ route, navigation }) => {  //in caso di problemi torna function

  const textArtist = route.params;

  const screen = Dimensions.get("screen");

  const geniusUrl = 'https://api.genius.com';

  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  const [nameArtist, setNameArtist] = useState([]);
  const [picArtist, setPicArtist] = useState([]);
  const [bioArtist, setBioArtist] = useState([]);
  const [bioNotFound, setBioNotFound] = useState(true);

  const [topSongJson, setTopSongJson] = useState([]);
  const [idArtist, setIdArtist] = useState([]);

  auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {    //<-------
    const preferredArtistRef = firestore().collection('preferredArtist')
    if (user) {
      isSignedUser(true)
      setUid(user.uid)
      preferredArtistRef
        .get()
        .then(querySnapshot => {
          querySnapshot.forEach(documentSnapshot => {
            setDocumentId(documentSnapshot.id)
            if (documentSnapshot.data().uid == uid && documentSnapshot.data().artist == nameArtist) {
              setPreferred(true)
              console.log('add')
            }
          })
        })
    } else {
      isSignedUser(false)
    }
  });

  const [uid, setUid] = useState();
  const [documentId, setDocumentId] = useState();

  const [signedUser, isSignedUser] = useState();
  const visibleIcon = signedUser ? 30 : 0;

  const [preferred, setPreferred] = useState();
  const star = preferred ? 'star' : 'star-o';

  const RightContent = () =>  // <--------
    <FontAwesome
      name={star}
      color='#673AB7'
      size={visibleIcon}
      onPress={() => {
        const preferredArtistRef = firestore().collection('preferredArtist')
        if (preferred) {
          setPreferred(false)
          preferredArtistRef
            .doc(documentId)
            .delete()
            .then(() => {
              console.log('Artist remove')
            })
            .catch((error) => alert(error))
        } else {
          setPreferred(true)
          preferredArtistRef
            .add({
              uid: uid,
              artist: nameArtist
            })
            .then(querySnapshot => {
              console.log('Artist added in prefer')
            })
            .catch((error) => alert(error))
        }
      }}
      style={styles.star}
    />

  const ButtonSong = (textArtist, textSong) => {
    navigation.dispatch(StackActions.push('Search song', { textArtist, textSong }))
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(geniusUrl + '/search?q=' + textArtist, {
      headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + geniusToken }
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {

        setTopSongJson(data.response.hits)

        for (const value of data.response.hits) {

          if (value.result.primary_artist.name.normalize("NFD").replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "").toLowerCase() ==
            textArtist.normalize("NFD").replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "").toLowerCase().trim()) {

            setNameArtist(value.result.primary_artist.name)
            setPicArtist(value.result.primary_artist.header_image_url)
            setIdArtist(value.result.primary_artist.id)

            return fetch(geniusUrl + value.result.primary_artist.api_path, {
              headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + geniusToken }
            })
              .then((response) => response.json())
              .then((text) => {

                var buildBio = ""
                for (const child of text.response.artist.description.dom.children) {
                  if (child == '') {
                    buildBio = buildBio.concat('\n\n')
                  }
                  else if (child.tag == 'p') {
                    for (const childP of child.children) {
                      if (typeof childP == 'string')
                        buildBio = buildBio.concat(childP)
                      else {
                        if (childP.tag == 'a') {
                          for (const childA of childP.children) {
                            if (typeof childA == 'string')
                              buildBio = buildBio.concat(childA)
                            else {
                              if (childA.tag == 'em') {
                                for (const childEM of childA.children) {
                                  if (typeof childEM == 'string')
                                    buildBio = buildBio.concat(childEM)
                                }
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        }
                        else if (childP.tag == 'em') {
                          for (const childEM of childP.children) {
                            if (typeof childEM == 'string')
                              buildBio = buildBio.concat(childEM)
                            else {
                              if (childEM.tag == 'a') {
                                for (const childA of childEM.children) {
                                  if (typeof childA == 'string')
                                    buildBio = buildBio.concat(childA)
                                }
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
                if (buildBio != "" && buildBio != "?") {
                  setBioArtist(buildBio)
                  setBioNotFound(false)
                }

              })
              .catch((error) => console.log(error))
              .finally(() => setLoading(false))
          }
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error))
      .finally(() => setLoading(false));

  }, []);


  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {isLoading ? (
        <View style={styles.loading}>
          <ActivityIndicator
            size='large'
            color='#673AB7'
          />
        </View>
      ) : (
        bioNotFound ? (
          <View style={styles.loading}>
            <Text>
              Sorry!
            </Text>
            <Text>
              Your request didin't produce any result
            </Text>
          </View>
        ) : (
          <FlatList
            ListHeaderComponent={
              <>
                <View style={styles.titleView}>
                  <Text style={styles.textTitle}>
                    {nameArtist}
                  </Text>
                  <RightContent />
                </View>
                <View
                  style={styles.titleRow}
                />
                <View style={{ padding: 10 }}>
                  <Image
                    source={{ uri: picArtist }}
                    style={[styles.image, { width: { screen }.width }]}
                  />
                  <Text style={styles.textBio}>
                    {bioArtist}
                  </Text>
                </View>
                <View style={{ paddingBottom: 20 }}>
                  <Text style={styles.titleTopSong}>
                    Top Song by {nameArtist}
                  </Text>
                  <View
                    style={styles.titleRow}
                  />
                </View>
              </>
            }
            data={topSongJson}
            keyExtractor={item => item.result.id}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
              item.result.primary_artist.id == idArtist ?
                <View style={styles.card}>
                  <Card>
                    <Card.Title
                      title={item.result.title}
                      subtitle={item.result.primary_artist.name}
                      right={() =>
                        <FontAwesome5
                          name='headphones-alt'
                          color='#673AB7'
                          size={30}
                          onPress={() => ButtonSong(item.result.primary_artist.name, item.result.title)}
                          style={styles.headphones}
                        />
                      }
                    />
                  </Card>
                </View>
                : null
            )}
          />
        )
      )}
    </View>
  )
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  // all styles
});

export default ArtistScreen;
```

Comment: Can you show us when you call `auth().onAuthStateChanged(/*etc*/)`? For example, is it in a useEffect?

Comment: @NicholasTower it isn't in a useEffect, but in the screen a useEffect is called for the api call. If you want I publish the code of the whole screen.

Comment: If the auth callback is being called multiple times, then either you're signing in/out multiple times (doesn't seem likely, since you only mentioned clicking things, not logging in), or you're registering for the event multiple times. So seeing when you call onAuthStateChanged could reveal that you're registering multiple times.

Comment: @NicholasTower i edit the post

Comment: Every time your `ArtistScreen` renders (which can be multiple times) you call `auth()` again and add a new changed listener. React components are pure functions that return react elements. Any side effects, like adding event listeners, need to be done in hooks.

Comment: @AndyRay thanks for the information. Do you have a solution to the problem?

Answer (score 2):

```
auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
```

You are calling this in the body of your component. Every time ArtistScreen renders for any reason, you will add an additional listener to the authStateChanged event. These listeners never get removed, even after leaving the page.

Instead, you need to do this just once, in a useEffect:

```
const ArtistScreen = ({ route, navigation }) => { 
  // ...
  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      // ... etc
    });
    return unsubscribe; // This will let it clean up when the ArtistScreen unmounts
  }, []); // The empty dependency array means it will only run once, when mounting
```

Comment: I did what you suggested. Now the problem is that it `consoles.log('add')` is never triggered, and so I can't save the favorite and then have to delete it in case the user wants to delete it. Also I noticed that if I reload the program with the screen already open, `console.log ('add')` is triggered